# circular dependenct on android studio flamingo

Tags: circular-dependency

I keep getting circular dependency error when I try to build the project but the error does not state where exactly the circular dependency is

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekZaq.png)

thanks in advance for the help

I disabled parallel run check the imports and the manifest

Comment: I reset my settings to default and now the error have more information:

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.CircularReferenceException: Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:processDebugResources
\--- :app:processDebugResources (*)

Comment: Please add relevant additional information to the post directly by [edit]ing it, the comments are a place to ask for clarification and notify users, not for adding information.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)